# Awk: working only with text blocks from input

Tags: awk

I know that doing HTML parsing with tools that are not actually designed for it is wrong. I do it to learn and understand Awk.

I have a large HTML file that has two sections on which I need to work, other parts don't matter to me. So I decided to select the parts on which I would be working first. Code:

```
cat ./txt.txt

BBBBB
BBBBB
BBBBB
section1
AAAAA1
AAAAA1
AAAAA1
end_section1
BBBBB
BBBBB
BBBBB
section2
AAAAA2
AAAAA2
AAAAA2
end_section2
BBBBB
BBBBB
BBBBB
```

```
cat ./txt.txt | awk ' 

# First block
# I will select the first block to work with, it starts with "section1"
# and ends at the first entry of "end_section1" string; for this block I need to apply one regular expression.
/section1/ {
      found=1
}

found {
      gsub(/^AAAAA1$/,"AAAAA1_1", $0)
      print
      if (/end_section1/) {
        exit
      }
}

# Second block
# I select the second block from the file and apply completely different regular expressions to it.
/section2/ {
      found=1
}

found {
      gsub(/^AAAAA2$/,"AAAAA2_2", $0)
      print
      if (/end_section2/) {
        exit
      }
}

'
```

I am trying to get the following output:

```
AAAAA1_1
AAAAA1_1
AAAAA1_1
AAAAA2_2
AAAAA2_2
AAAAA2_2
```

This only works with one block. The problem is in `exit` as far as I understand because Awk stops working.
So far, I have no idea how to work independent with blocks of text and how to solve this problem. Maybe someone can give me a hint.

In general, the task is to process independently two blocks of text and the file, and output only what was gotten after parsing. If someone can give me a link to a good Awk style code, I would also appreciate it.

---

EDIT by Ed Morton to show good awk code style applied to your code as you asked for and to help make your code easier to understand. The following is the output of pretty-printing your code using `gawk -o- ...`:

```
BEGIN {
        print "addsomelong lines<link>" url "</link>"
}

# First block
# I will select the first block to work with, it starts with "main_page"
# and ends at the first entry of </section> string; for this block I need to apply one regular expression.
/main_page/ {
        found = 1
}

found {
        gsub(/<\/div>/, "123", $0)
        gsub(/.*title>/, "1234", $0)
        print
        if (/<\/section>/) {
                exit
        }
}

# Second block
# I select the second block from the file and apply completely different regular expressions to it.
/<div class="items">/ {
        found = 1
}

found {
        gsub(/<\/div>/, "ABC", $0)
        gsub(/.*title>/, "QWERTY", $0)
        print
        if (/publication/) {
                exit
        }
}

# Completing the work
END {
        print "\nadd\nshort\nline"
}
```

Comment: replace first `exit` with `next`

Comment: I added a well-formatted version of your code to your question since you asked for formatting tips. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you. FWIW I disagree with @karakfas suggestion (I think you probably should use different flags for each block and set them to zero when the terminating match occurs) but without a [mcve] we're both just guessing at what you might want.

Comment: @EdMorton I added an example and cut the script.

Comment: Don''t keep adding onto your question as that just makes it confusing, just fix the question to contain 1 version of your script instead of 3 and the 1 set of sample input/output you want us to consider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making minimal changes to your script to make it easy to identify the differences:

```
$ cat tst.awk
# First section
found1 {
    if (/^end_section1$/) {
        found1=0
    }
    else {
        gsub(/^AAAAA1$/,"AAAAA1_1", $0)
        print
    }
}

/^section1$/ {
    found1=1
}

# Second section
found2 {
    if (/^end_section2$/) {
        found2=0
    }
    else {
        gsub(/^AAAAA2$/,"AAAAA2_2", $0)
        print
    }
}

/^section2$/ {
    found2=1
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk txt.txt
AAAAA1_1
AAAAA1_1
AAAAA1_1
AAAAA2_2
AAAAA2_2
AAAAA2_2
```

The above assumes there are no overlapping or nested ranges and that if the begin regexp is matched then the end regexp will also occur after it.